# List and count distinct values across multiple columns in Excel

Tags: microsoft-excel, worksheet-function, microsoft-excel-2016

I've spent a good few hours trying different solutions across the web but haven't found anything that resolves my issue. I want to be able to count the number of instances of each value across 5 lists.

For context, its a project management database where entries can list up to 5 partners per project (these are currently as 5 separate cells). In the collation sheet I want to be able to count the number of times each unique partner was worked with.

My data would look like:

[image: Data]

And I want to be able to generate:

[image: Results]

The solution also needs to be something that is self updating, e.g. so when Project 6 is entered and lists Partner A and Partner G, the "Number of times worked with" for Partner A would update to 4, and Partner G would be added to the list and given a 1.

Any help would be hugely appreciated, thanks

Comment: It can be done easier in O365, but you probably don't have `UNIQUE` or `TEXTJOIN` in 2016.  You could also do this easily with Power Query, but it would not be dynamic as would a formula.

Answer (score 0):

you can use the =COUNTIF(range, condition)

let's assume you data is in a sheet called "projects and partners"

and your report is in a sheet called "report"

the formula would look like this:

```
=COUNTIF('projects and partners'!B2:I37,A2)
```

[image]

- `'projects and partners'!B2:I37` : is the range you wanna count in
- `A2` : is the value you wanna look for

and now you drag (copy) the formula from B2 to B7 and it'll adjust accordingly

Comment: My problem is that the partner names (A2 in your example) aren't pre-determined static fields. People will be writing in new names etc, so column A would need to be a self-updating list of distinct values across my 5 partner name columns.

Answer (score 0):

I've managed to achieve what I wanted with

> =IFERROR(IFERROR(IFERROR(IFERROR(LOOKUP(2,1/(COUNTIF($H$2:H2,$B$3:$B$11)=0),$B$3:$B$11),LOOKUP(2,1/(COUNTIF($H$2:H2,$D$3:$D$6)=0),$D$3:$D$6)),LOOKUP(2,1/(COUNTIF($H$2:H2,$F$3:$F$8)=0),$F$3:$F$8)),LOOKUP(2,1/(COUNTIF($H$2:H2,$E$3:$E$8)=0),$E$3:$E$8)), LOOKUP(2,1/(COUNTIF($H$2:H2,$C$3:$C$8)=0),$C$3:$C$8))

This creates the self-updating list of new partner names across the 5 columns that I can use COUNTTIF against.

Which is ridiculously complex but it works. Very much open to suggestions to make it simpler!

Comment: I'd look into array formulas to make this a bit shorter: https://www.listendata.com/2013/05/excel-3-ways-to-extract-unique-values.html

Comment: Consider using a **Table** so you can use structured references for the ranges, which can automatically update as they change in size.